# Change depth in existing SVN working copy without redownloading

Tags: svn, sparse-checkout, svn-update

I have a working copy of an entire SVN repository, but I want to change it into a sparse working copy because of disk space issues.

One way to do this would be:

```
svn up --set-depth immediates projects
svn up --set-depth infinity projects/project1
svn up --set-depth infinity projects/project2
```

However, that would first delete `project1` and `project2`, then redownload them. This is really inconvenient, because they're very large and the server's upload speed is very low. I tried this (with another, smaller, part of the repo, as an experiment):

```
svn up --set-depth infinity projects/project1
svn up --set-depth infinity projects/project2
svn up --set-depth immediates projects
```

But then the last command just undoes the first 2.

How can I set the depth of a working copy without it immediately updating/changing it, so I can have the chance to correctly configure subdirectories first?

Or is there another way to accomplish what I want, e.g. by copying `project1` and `project2` to a safe location first?

Answer (score 32):

Woo hoo, I had this problem, and TortoiseSVN has supported solutions for both add and delete an item from the sparse checkout.
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html

1.To add:
In windows explorer, Right click on the checked out folder, then use TortoiseSVN ? Repo-Browser to bring up the repository browser. Find the sub-folder you would like to add to your working copy, then use Context Menu ? Update item to revision....

2.To delete; 
From your root, right-click / Repo-Browser / Update item to revision; then select 'Exclude'.

Comment: You don't have to go through the repo browser.  TortoiseSVN's contextual menu has the "Update to revision..." option.  Just right-click on the excluded folders themselves rather than the working directory root. Of course, this assumes a stub folder (empty excluded folder) exists in your path.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up hacking it:

- Manually edit the depth setting to "immediates" for `projects` *.
- Hard delete (not SVN delete) all children of `projects` except `project1` and `project2`
- `svn up projects`

[*] To do this, open up `projects/.svn/entries` in a text editor and change

```
b125e325-6f7c-4931-9942-d1ea1ea1441a
X
```

into

```
b125e325-6f7c-4931-9942-d1ea1ea1441a







immediates
X
```

**Note:** That UUID-looking line is probably different per repo, and `X` is actually hex value `0x0C` which I can't get displayed here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but what you wrote doesn't seem be possible in SVN 1.7, since the metadata format looks different.

Here's what I ended up doing (using the directories in your situation). First, I copied `project1` and `project2` somewhere safe.

```
svn co --depth immediates svn_url/projects
```

This checks out `projects` with empty directories `project1` and `project2`. I then delete the empty folders and put the actual directories in their place. SVN gives me some weird messages but it seems to work and allows me to commit. (It does not work with `--depth empty` and then copying the folders in, but `immediates` seems to work.)

I agree this situation is not ideal, but that's why I'm switching to Git for future projects! I've used SVN for a long time, but it is getting beyond hope.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like reviving an old SO Question.

I have been working with a very similar problem where I branch from trunk to create a release package but due to limitations I have to clone files which are only intended for dev.

```
asset
└── js
    └── some
        └── directories
            ├── assets
            │   ├── files ...
            ├── dev       **<------------ This folder needs to be empty**
            │   ├── apis
            │   ├── campaign
            │   ├── features
            │   ├── modules
            │   ├── main.js
            │   └── tags
            └── release
                ├── apis
                ├── data
                ├── features
                ├── modules
                ├── main.js
                └── tags
```

I decided that I would exclude the dev files to remove the temptation to patch a fix in the release branch in the wrong directory.

I do a lot of sparse checkouts to avoid large folders in trunk but have never done it retrospectively on a working copy. It seems this is pretty straight forward.

To modify the working copy so that `asset/js/some/directories/dev`is empty you can simply run the `svn co` command again on the working copy.

In my case the following works

```
svn co --depth empty ^/branches/releases/latest/asset/js/some/directories/dev \
asset/js/some/directories/dev
```

You are basically running a partial checkout on your pre-existing working copy and this will work at any level. In the original case you would simply run the following.

```
svn co --depth immediates ^/branches/mybranch/projects projects
svn co --depth immediates ^/branches/mybranch/project1 project1
svn co --depth immediates ^/branches/mybranch/project2 project2
```

For those that don't know the caret `^` is shorthand for the repository root so it works like a relative path on your repository a little like `../some/location`.

The key here is that you are not creating a new working copy to fix your problem. You are running these commands on your existing working copy and resetting the depth of your chosen directories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people are doing things the hard way in the other answers.

Since Subversion 1.6 it's possible to simply do
`svn update --set-depth exclude <directory_you_want_to_prune_from_local_working_copy>`