# TortoiseSVN: Adding additional files after using SVN Checkout dialog "Only this item" option

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout, sparse-checkout

Our department is planning on using the "SVN Checkout" option within Tortoise SVN.  In that dialog, we select the "Only this item" option and then we click the "Choose items" button and choose all the relevant files we want to check-out.  Let's assume a user will make a mistake, and forgot to check out an important file.  What is the easiest way to go back and choose that file (or list of files) from trunk?

[image]

## EDIT:

**Suggested changes to @Chad's answer:**

**A.) If the parent folder of the folder(s) or file(s) you are checking out DOES NOT EXIST in the working copy, then do the following:**

1. Open a **Repo-browser** for the repository.
2. Right-click the files that were missed and choose **Checkout...**.
3. *Fix/Set the Checkout directory to where the files should go (add the folders from the folder you clicked to the parent folder of the folder/file you are checking out and make sure you are using backslash characters)*
4. Click **OK**.
5. You will get a warning that the "Target folder is not empty". Go ahead and choose the **Checkout into the non empty folder** option.

The files will be added to the working copy.

**DISCLAIMER:** *If you do not follow step #3, the working copy of the checked out files will be in a strange location not relative to the rest of the files.*

**B.) If the parent folder of the folder(s) or file(s) you are checking out DOES EXIST in the working copy, then do the following:**

1. Open a **Repo-browser** for the repository.
2. *Navigate to the parent folder of the file you intend to checkout (avoids the step of having to fix the "Checkout Directory")*
3. Right-click the files that were missed and choose **Checkout...**.
4. Click **OK**.
5. You will get a warning that the "Target folder is not empty". Go ahead and choose the **Checkout into the non empty folder** option.

The files will be added to the working copy.

## EDIT #2:

**Suggested update to @gbjbaanb's proposed answer:**

**To include new folders/files to working copy:**

1. Right click root folder of checked out folder > select "TortoiseSVN" > select "Repo-browser"
2. Enter credentials (if authentication is cleared in TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data) > click "OK"
3. Right click items in either the file explorer panel or the file detail panel within the Repository Browser dialog > select "Update item to Revision" > take all defaults in the Update to Revision dialog > click "OK"
4. Enter credentials (if authentication is cleared in TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data) > click "OK"

**NOTE:** *Repeat step #3 and #4 for all new folders/files being added*

**DISCLAIMER:** *Assume you are only adding new folders or files to your working copy/checked out folder.*

**To exclude folders/files from working copy:**

1. Right click folder or file you wish to exclude
2. Select Tortoise SVN > Update to Revision
3. Click "Choose items..." button under the "Update Depth" section of the Update to Revision dialog
4. Enter credentials (if authentication is cleared in TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data) > click "OK"
5. Uncheck relevant folder(s) or file(s) > click "OK"

That's the method I used with a very large repository. Only the bits I needed were checked out, when I needed them.

Comment: Would love to learn how to do this on the command line as well.

Comment: Not sure how to do it from the command line, but if you want to automate it, look at SharpSVN .NET library.  It's available in there.

Comment: Related: [Change depth in existing SVN working copy without redownloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223341/change-depth-in-existing-svn-working-copy-without-redownloading)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You right-click on the root, select repo-browser, find the relevant bits you want to download to your working copy, right click and select the "update to revision".

To remove items you have downloaded, right click on the item in your working copy, select the same menu (update to revision) and select "exclude" from the depth box.

That's the method I used with a very large repository. Only the bits I needed were checked out, when I needed them.

Comment: +1 ... this is a much simpler workflow than @Chad's answer.  See EDIT #2.

Comment: It is also "more correct". The other answer results in a separate working copy for the previously-missing items nested within the original working copy, so tools such as "merge" error out.

Answer (score 5):

There are two scenarios when adding missed files and folders to a working copy: The **Missing** parent folder scenario and the **Present** parent folder scenario.

**Scenario 1**: The working copy is **Missing** the parent folder of the missed folders or files

1. Open a **Repo-browser** for the repository.
2. Right-click the files that were missed and choose **Checkout...**.
3. Set the **Checkout directory** to where the files should go. From an existing folder in the working copy, add the path of missing folders leading to the folder/files you are checking out. Make sure to use backslash characters.
4. Click **OK**.
5. You will get a warning that the "Target folder is not empty". Go ahead and choose the **Checkout into the non empty folder** option.

The files will be added to the working copy.

**DISCLAIMER:** *If you do not follow step #3, the working copy of the checked out files will be in a strange location not relative to the rest of the files.*

**Scenario 2**: The working copy **Contains** the parent folder of the missed folders or files

1. Open a **Repo-browser** for the repository.
2. Navigate to the parent folder of the file you intend to checkout (this avoids having to change the "Checkout Directory")
3. Right-click the files that were missed and choose **Checkout...**.
4. Click **OK**.
5. You will get a warning that the "Target folder is not empty". Go ahead and choose the **Checkout into the non empty folder** option.

The files will be added to the working copy.

Comment: +1 .... see EDIT.  I'm still testing out a bunch of scenarios ... so my suggested answer for you will get more complex so we cover all of the scenarios in the answer, at which point, I will mark yours as the answer.  This answer was very helpful to get me started.

Comment: Sorry I changed my mind.  The other workflow is a little easier, so I'm marking that one as the answer.  Thanks for your input.