# In TortoiseSVN how to checkout additional project folders that were missed before?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

- In windows explorer I go into a newly created folder named "projects"
- I right click "svn checkout", click the "choose items" button and select 9 of 10 project folders.
- tortoiseSVN checks out the 9 project folders into my "projects" folder
- Later I realize I also need the 10the project folder to be checked out that I didn't check before.

MY QUESTION: How do I get tortoiseSVN to check out the 10th project folder in the same location, under the "projects" folder alongside the other 9 folders I checked out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TortoiseSVN: Adding additional files after using SVN Checkout dialog "Only this item" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709722/tortoisesvn-adding-additional-files-after-using-svn-checkout-dialog-only-this)

Answer (score 5):

Just do a right click on project folder -> update to revision. You will get this dialog:

[image]

Click on `Choose items ...` where you can add your additional folders.

Comment: @draca: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Would be nice if you can accept the answer as solution.