# Subversion: Query Sparse Checkout Status

Tags: svn, sparse-checkout

There are a number of posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223341/change-depth-in-existing-svn-working-copy-without-redownloading/15709514), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945/can-you-do-a-partial-checkout-with-subversion), not to mention the [official documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)) which ask/explain how to perform a sparse checkout, but I don't see any post on how to query the depth of a folder or a series of folders.

Is there anyway to ask Subversion, "what was the depth setting passed to svn update --set-depth?" on a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn info` will tell you.  Here's a directory updated with `svn update --set-depth=files`:

```
> svn info "C:\path\to\directory"
Path: C:\path\to\directory
Working Copy Root Path: C:\path
URL: http://svn.example.com/path/to/directory
Relative URL: ^/path/to/directory
Repository Root: http://svn.example.com/path
Repository UUID: 3183f4db-b256-8143-8013-6b50bc517e3e
Revision: 4860
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: files
Last Changed Author: abc
Last Changed Rev: 1234
Last Changed Date: 2014-12-09 14:52:55 -0500 (Tue, 09 Dec 2014)
```

The line `Depth: files` indicates the update depth.  When the depth is `infinity`, this line is just missing.  Otherwise, it will be one of "empty", "files", or "immediates" (those listed in the help for `svn update`).

Note that for sparse checkouts, it will be `empty` because sparse checkouts don't really map to any of the other values.