# SVN - how to transform individually checked-out sub-folders into sparse checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

SVN repo looks like this:

top/
top/one
top/two
top/three
  ...etc

You don't want to checkout the entire **top** folder but you don't know about [SVN's sparse checkout feature](https://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#sparse).
So you check-out repo folder **top/one** into **C:\svn\top\one** and then you checkout repo folder **top/two** into **C:\svn\top\two**

At this point, both of the checked-out folders have their own **.svn** folder

Then you discover [sparse checkouts](https://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#sparse).

**QUESTION**

How do you transform the "standalone" checkout of these two folders into a sparse checkout of the top-level folder *with minimal re-checking out*?

Is it as simple as initiating a sparse check-out while not overwriting existing items and then simply deleting the pre-existing `.svn` folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN works recursively, which means that every folder is mostly independent from its parent. So the issue comes from the .SVN in the parent folder, this is the one you want to recreate from scratch.

Rename your former folder (*.old*) and create a new one. Do your *Sparse Checkout* in that folder. It should download the files but you can prevent that with `--depth empty`.

Then, move your old folders back in the freshly created *Sparse Checkout* folder and *Clean* it. SVN will scan and repair the folder recursively.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.

Comment: Well, glad to confirm your though, sorry if this is not the answer your expected. Take a look at this, it is similar to your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223341/change-depth-in-existing-svn-working-copy-without-redownloading